# Laravel 5.2 Only one specific route not found, but it does exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

No matter what I try, the route `/authenticate/{code}` returns a `NotFoundHttpException`.

My route in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/authenticate/{code}', ['as' => 'authenticate', 'uses' => 'FrontendController@getAuthenticate']);
```

When I am calling the route:

```
URL::route('authenticate', $code)
```

On my local machine it runs it just fine, but on my production server, it takes me to a `NotFoundHttpException` page.

It does site inside of the `web` middleware group.

I have tried (with no success):

- resetting the github repo on the server (fresh install)
- `composer update`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan view:clear`
- `php artisan route:clear`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- changing the route from `authenticate` to `authenticate-email`

What could it be? Every other route on the site works, it is just this one that doesnt.

Comment: have you tried confirming that the route shows up when you do `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @dargue3 Yes I have, it does.

Comment: Just as a troubleshooting step, maybe try changing it to `Route::any(...` to see if it gets picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think to advise is switching from using the URL Facade to using the built in helper function `$url = route('authenticate', ['code' => $code]);` I only say this because I can't seem to find in the docs how you hint at URI parameters when using `URL::route()` :)

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the URL after you fetch it for that named route?

Comment: I changed the `URL::route` to `route()` in one email and still tested the other... stupid mistake. haha thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue. I deleted the route, then copy another working route and changed the route name and parameters with the one. And It Worked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this but I just had exactly the same problem, nothing I did would make the route work. It was a really simple route: `Route::get('/search', ['middleware' => 'shop_session','uses' => 'Cinder\StoreController@viewProducts']);`

Did all the things you did. In the end I moved the route to the top of my routes file, ran `php artisan route:cache` and it worked.

Not a great answer and I've got no idea why it worked but it did. Maybe worth a try?